# Best cheap 3D printer, using FDM, with large print volume?

Tags: desktop-printer

What are people's opinions on the most affordable 3D printer with a large print volume, of 200mm x 200mm x 180mm minimum, with a good quality over 100 microns?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. We need to make this question more specific for it to be a good fit for the StackExchange format. General opinion or survey questions are discouraged. For example, you could ask "what is the lowest-cost FDM printer with build volume of 300mm cube?" And that would be a better question. (Or whatever details are pertinent to your needs.)

Comment: @RyanCarlyle is it ok now?

Comment: I think that we should just avoid "recommend me a printer" questions altogether. The answers will always be highly subjective (no matter how specific you state your requirements) and inevitably go out of date (the printer market is rapidly changing). A better question would be "Does printer model X fit my requirements Y?".

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I'm not saying recommend me a printer I'm trying to see what your opinions are on the best reasonable sized printer

Comment: "Most affordable" is also too vague. A college student will have a lower reference for affordable, while a professional engineer could have a budget in thousands of dollars. Provide a price range to your question for better results.

Comment: It's all of your opinion, I just wanted to see what you guys thought was the best affordable one in your eyes

Comment: Better ask "Which printers can do 200x200x200 mm at 100 microns" You can then select the cheapest from that list.

Comment: @LarsPötter I wouldn't consider that a good question either. The answer would be unreasonably broad (basically, almost all printers except some very small ones) and go out of date (printers entering and leaving the market).